# GWT-GIN Multiple Implementations?

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin

I have the following code

```
public class AppGinModule extends AbstractGinModule{
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ContactListView.class).to(ContactListViewImpl.class);
        bind(ContactDetailView.class).to(ContactDetailViewImpl.class);
    }
}

@GinModules(AppGinModule.class) 
public interface AppInjector extends Ginjector{
    ContactDetailView getContactDetailView();
    ContactListView getContactListView();
}
```

In my entry point

```
AppInjector appInjector = GWT.create(AppGinModule.class);
appInjector.getContactDetailsView();
```

Here `ContactDetailView` is always bind with `ContactsDetailViewImpl`. But i want that to bind with `ContactDetailViewImplX` under some conditions.

How can i do that? Pls help me.

Comment: What are the conditions under which you want to substitute different implementations? For different browsers?

Comment: No. It's for user privileges. Two views for two different set of users. As like when we use factories we will get different implementations based on some condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't declaratively tell Gin to inject one implementation sometimes and another at other times. You can do it with a [`Provider`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings) or a [`@Provides` method](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) though.

`Provider` Example:

```
public class MyProvider implements Provider<MyThing> {
    private final UserInfo userInfo;
    private final ThingFactory thingFactory;

    @Inject
    public MyProvider(UserInfo userInfo, ThingFactory thingFactory) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
        this.thingFactory = thingFactory;
    }

    public MyThing get() {
        //Return a different implementation for different users
        return thingFactory.getThingFor(userInfo);
    }   
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractGinModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
      //other bindings here...

      bind(MyThing.class).toProvider(MyProvider.class);
  }
}
```

`@Provides` Example:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        //other bindings here...
    }

    @Provides
    MyThing getMyThing(UserInfo userInfo, ThingFactory thingFactory) {
        //Return a different implementation for different users
        return thingFactory.getThingFor(userInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this is what i m searching.